# Special Characters sort in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, db2

I have the table named as "Contacts" have column named as id and name. Respective column Values are shown below.

```
ID    |   Name
1     |   ABC
3     |   DEF
2     |   GHI
~!    |   JKL
null  |   MNO
null  |   PQR
```

I need a query for the special characters to be listed at top row like below.

```
ID    |   Name
~!    |   JKL
1     |   ABC
2     |   GHI
3     |   DEF
null  |   MNO
null  |   PQR
```

I have query to make null values listed below

```
select ID, Name 
from Contacts 
order by ID NULLS LAST
```

Please help me to get special characters to get sort in first row.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server <> db2. Please don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN id NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' THEN 1
   WHEN id IS NULL THEN 3
   ELSE 2 END, id
```

use regex

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
ORDER BY name REGEXP '^[a-z]' ASC, name
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `case` statement, is standard for all SQL brands. But is not index friendly:

```
Select ID, Name 
from Contacts 
order by 
( case 
    when id like '[a-Z][a-Z]%' then 1
    when id is null then null
    else 0
  end
),
ID NULLS LAST
```

**Notice** `'[a-Z][a-Z]%'` is only valid for sql-server. You need more elaborate sentence to be all brand compliant, something like `when id >= 'a' and id <= 'z' then 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @tab table(ID Varchar(10) , Name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @tab
SELECT '1'  ,'ABC' Union ALL
SELECT '3'  ,'DEF' Union all
SELECT '2'  ,'GHI' Union all
SELECT '~!'  ,'JKL' Union all
SELECT null,'MNO' Union all
SELECT null,'PQR'
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT ID , Name,ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by Id)Seq FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
                SELECT *, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('^~![a-z]',Id) >0 Then 0  
                   WHEN  ISNULL(ID,0) =0 THEN 1
                     ELSE Id END Seq  FROM @tab
        )Dt
    WHERE Dt.ID IS NOT NULL 
)Final

UNION ALL 

    SELECT ID,Name,ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by Id)Seq1 FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM   
        (
            SELECT *, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('^~![a-z]',Id) >0 Then 0  
                         WHEN  ISNULL(ID,0) =0 THEN 1
                         ELSE Id END Seq  FROM @tab
        )Dt
        WHERE Dt.ID IS  NULL
)Final
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Output

```
ID      Name    Seq
-------------------
~!       JKL     1
1       ABC     2
2       GHI     3
3       DEF     4
NULL    MNO     1
NULL    PQR     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to sort your ID as per your requirement where the row with `NULL ID` will be sorted in the last.

```
Select ID, Name from contact order by
case
    when ID IS NULL then 1
    else 0
end,ID
```

For ordering a string column:SQL uses alphabetical order.

NULLs are the lowest value,
then special characters, 
then numbers, 
then letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in db2 you have just to sort by id, null will be last

```
select ID, Name 
from Contacts 
order by ID
```

otherwise you can replace all digit by Nothing and then '' by null and order like it

```
select                                                           
ifnull(translate(id, '          ', '0123456789'), '') nodigit,   
tmp.*                                                            
from Contatcs tmp                                                         
order by 1 desc
```