# Collections.sort() and ORDER BY in sql (MISMATCH)

Tags: java, sql, collections, sql-order-by

I have values like

```
ZBX-A_INSTANCES
AGAAAACTX
_MONITORSTATUS
PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION
1TEST1
_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01
```

..in multiple rows of a column for a particular condition

I need the output as
1TEST1,AGAAAACTX,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,ZBX-A_INSTANCES,_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS as this would be input parameter for the query framed from JAVA using Collections.sort() for the same input of strings passed in java

---

I tried out ORDER BY resulting as
_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS,1TEST1,AGAAAACTX,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,ZBX-A_INSTANCES

Tried for

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN Parameter NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' THEN 1
ELSE 2
END
```

from [Special Characters sort in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801760/special-characters-sort-in-sql)
resulting this way
AGAAAACTX,1TEST1,ZBX-A_INSTANCES,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS

Comment: From the linked stackoverflow post, your query has a missing `id` at the end. Original post says `ORDER BY...END, id`. That should solve the issue.

Comment: This way it worked
1TEST1,AGAAAACTX,_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,ZBX-A_INSTANCES

Comment: If it has resolved the issue, please mark this question as resolved

Comment: No.. It wasn't solved.. Kindly look on the result above and my expected output

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your LIKE seems to involve regex, which is product specific feature.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Just retrofitting the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801760/special-characters-sort-in-sql) stackoverflow answer to suit your query:

```
select Parameter from table_name
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN Parameter NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' THEN 1
ELSE 2
end, Parameter
```

Comment: 1TEST1,AGAAACTX,_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,ZBX-A_INSTANCES was the result of query you mentioned... 

My expected is
1TEST1,AGAAAACTX,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,ZBX-A_INSTANCES,_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS

Comment: The above query in postgres resulted in 1TEST1, AGAAAACTX, PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION, ZBX-A_INSTANCES, _CEMCYPRESSTEST_01, _MONITORSTATUS. Not sure why it work differently in SQL server

Comment: Let that be the usual ORDER BY resulting 
1TEST1,AGAAAACTX,PERCENTAGE_UTILIZATION,ZBX-A_INSTANCES,_CEMCYPRESSTEST_01,_MONITORSTATUS
....... Is there a possibility to get the same result in java?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. Do you need the java code to sort the same set of strings?